# PythonAnywhere - Mysql error: 1044 (42000): Access denied

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to host a Python/Mysql project online with PythonAnywhere. When I attempt to connect to the database with: (host and password changed obviously)

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='host',user="BobbyQ",password='password',db='mm-database')
```

I get this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'BobbyQ'@'%' to database 'mm-database'
```

If I run `SHOW GRANTS` from Mysql console I get this:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for BobbyQ@%                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'BobbyQ'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3 |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `BobbyQ$default`.* TO 'BobbyQ'@'%'                                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `BobbyQ$mm-database`.* TO 'BobbyQ'@'%'                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I should be able to connect to the database at this point but I don't why I can't. How can I solve?

Comment: can you connect from the same machine with the mysql command line tool?

Comment: Are you connecting remotely or via `localhost`? If it's local you need to add an entry for `@localhost` as well.

Comment: @tadman I am connecting remotely (I am using the online consolle provided by PythonAnywhere)

Comment: @Flexo What do you mean more specifically? EDIT Sorry, I misunderstood because I didn't try (I thought I could connect anyway from the mysql command line tool but I can't). When I go the mysql consolle if I type `USE mm-database;` I get the same error: `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'BobbyQ'@'%' to database 'mm'`

Comment: SOLVED. I changed the database name (I tryed before but it didn' work, now it worked)

Answer (score 1):

With `sudo user` connect to the database (in the terminal) and create `newuser`:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
```

then go to the mysql database with this command :

```
USE MYSQL
```

and give all access to the user (`newuser`) with :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Write the name of the desired database instead of `database_name` and the desired username instead of `username`.

Finally :

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```